# Existence of a given limit.

Tags: limits, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Examine with justification,whether the following limit exists,

$\lim_{N\to \infty}$ $\int_{N}^{e^N}$$xe^{{-x^{2016}}}$$dx$

my logic is,  $\forall x<0$;  $x>$$xe^{{-x^{2016}}}$

now the integral  $\int_{N}^{e^N}$ $xdx$= ${1\over 2}$[$e^{2N}-N^2$]=0.5[$e^N-N$][$e^N+N$] $\to \infty$, as $N \to \infty$ because $e^N-N>0$ and $e^N+N \to \infty$.

as $x>$$xe^{{-x^{2016}}}$, by comparison $\lim_{N\to \infty}$ $\int_{N}^{e^N}$$xe^{{-x^{2016}}}$$dx$ $\to \infty$, hence the limit does not exist.

Is my approach all right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$xe^{-x^{2016}} \le xe^{-x^2}$$
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_N^{e^N}xe^{-x^2}dx=\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{2}\left[e^{-x^2}\right]^N_{e^N}=0$$
Hence the limit exists and should be zero.